# AppEngine: Will the items stored in a StringListProperty always remain in the same order?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

After looking through the docs on App Engine and the `StringListProperty` or the `ListProperty` I can't seem to find whether there is a guarantee on the order of the items in the list. That is, I'd like to be certain that the list order stays the same despite putting and getting from the DataStore:

```
instance = MyModel()
instance.list_property = ['a', 'b', 'c']
instance.put()

# Retrieve the model again
instance2 = MyModel.get_by_id(instance.key().id())
assert instance2.list_property == ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Does AppEngine make any guarantees about the order of items in a List or StringList?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, per [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entitiesandmodels.html#Lists),

> Order is preserved, so when entities
>   are returned by queries and get(),
>   list properties will have values in
>   the same order as when they were
>   stored.

It's the last sentence of the first paragraph at the URL I gave.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find it explicitly said in the documentation, but according to a [Google I/O talk about the DataStore](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgaL6NGpkB8), StringListProperty will be sorted the same way you put it there.